# Passing query parameters in dynamic URL to be used on another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I want to pass an extra parameter when navigating to another page. 
I am trying below with **?extraParam=[data.buildingName]** but not working.

```
 <Link href="/accounts/[accountId]/buildings/[buildingId]/gateways/[gatewayId]?extraParam=[data.buildingName]" as={`/accounts/${accountId}/buildings/${buildingId}/gateways/${row._id}`}>
            <Button type='button' color="info">Details</Button>
          </Link>
```

If I use **?extraParam=123"** then its working fine.

currently, when console.log(props) on destination page it shows below in query parameters. note the value of **extraParam**, it should come as BuldingName.

[image]
I guess I need to know how to access value from data.buildingName to add to the query string.

Comment: What is in [data.buildingName] when you do console.log()? Also, you may need to post the rest of your code for clarity.

Comment: data.buildingName is bulding name. i have edited question to show props.query values on destination page

Comment: I need actual value in extraParam instead of [data.buildingName]

Comment: Can you console.log [data.buildingName] name in the derived component, not the destination?

Comment: data.buildingName holds value for buildingName

Comment: Yes, I understand, I just wanted to see the type of data if its a string or not. Have you tried assigning the value to another variable Like buildingName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into passing the query params, through [the Next.js URL object](https://nextjs.org/docs#with-url-object).

Example:

```js
...
<Link
  href={{ pathname: '/path/to/page/file', query: { param1: 'value1' }, }}
  as="/rewrited-url"
>
    ...
</Link>
...
```